# Implicit reference conversions between array type

Tags: c#

In C# standard is written that exsists an implicit conversion between array according to the following rules:

> From an array-type S with an element type SE to an array-type T with
>   an element type TE, provided all of the  following are true:

- **S and T differ only in element type. In other words, S and T have the
  same number of dimensions.**

but if I make:

```
int[] j = { 1, 2 };
int[] k = { 1 };

k = j;
```

no compiler error is emitted. Maybe I didn't understand the meaning of this rule...

- **Both SE and TE are reference-types.**

but, again, in the example above the element type of `j` and `k` are value types.

- **An implicit reference conversion exists from SE to TE.**

here if I have:

```
int[] j = { 1, 2 };
short[] k = { 1, 5 };

j = k;
```

it seems like there can be an implicit conversion from element of type `short` to element of type `int` but the complier not compile. Emit an error.

Sincerely I can't figure how this rule work!

Comment: No conversion is required in this case, because both `i` and `j` are the same type, `int[]`. The dimensionality and element type are both identical.

Comment: Rule you quote simply does not apply here. Instead you should look at this:
**6.1.1 Identity conversion** An identity conversion converts from any type to the same type. This conversion exists such that an entity that already has a required type can be said to be convertible to that type.

Comment: @PetSerAl, but if I can't make k = j if j is short[] j and k is int[] k then all array conversions are implicity conversion of type identity conversion!

Comment: @xdevel2000 Implicit conversion from `string[]` to `object[]` is not an identity conversion.

Comment: @PetSerAl so string[] to object[] is the case of this rule "An implicit reference conversion exists from SE to TE" and this is why short[] to int[] can't be implicit converted?

Comment: @xdevel2000 Nor `int`, nor `short` are reference-types. And there is no implicit **reference** conversion between them. `short` to `int` conversion covered by **6.1.2 Implicit numeric conversions**.

Answer (score 2):

Both `j` and `k` are the same type. There are both an integer array, and they both have one dimension. So the array is entirely according to the rules.

These are the incorrect usings of the arrays as described in the documentation:

```
object[] j; int[] k;

int[,] j; int[] k;

float[] j; int[] k;
```

Answer (score 1):

What this code does is that it makes both `k` and `j` point to the same array, `{ 1, 2 }`

since both `k` and `j` are arrays with the same number of dimentions and the same element type, you can make one point to the other using this code

Answer (score 0):

1. Your arrays has the same element types.
2. Your arrays has value types in their elements.
3. Your arrays has the same dimentions - one.
4. [Multi-dimensional arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) looks like this: `int[,,]` (3 dimentions).

Answer (score 0):

S and T refer to the type of the arrays. In which case, `j` and `k` are both type `int[]` so there is no implicit conversion because they are the same type.

Since they don't differ in element type, their dimensions are irrelevant.